# () operator overloading on left side c++

Tags: c++

I have a class with overloaded () operator:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    string sound;
    Animal (string a): sound(a) {}

void operator()()
  {
    cout<<sound<<endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
    Animal dog("hau hau");
    dog();
}
```

but, is there any possibility I could get same result with () on the left side?

```
()dog;
```

I know I will probably never need this but I am just curious if it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do that: there is no syntax in C++ for a construct like that.

The purpose behind overloading `operator ()` is to let objects of your class participate in function invocation expressions, where your object represents the function being called. C++ has no syntax for calling functions or otherwise where parenthesis precede a primary expression (in your case, an identifier), so the answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 2):

No, because there has to be a primary expression before the `()`.

Also remember that the compiler will read this backwards, so he won't know that this is supposed to be a function.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. This is not possible. Not in a sane, safe, standard conforming way.

Answer (score 1):

1. `()` on the left side are for casting only
2. #YAGNI